# Why do I get this error : Malformed UTF-8 data

Tags: javascript, electron, cryptojs

```js
const license = fs.readFileSync('./license').toString();
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(license, 'mysecretkey123');
var originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

Last line throws an error : Malformed UTF-8 data

It works without error when I run this code in my Electron app before packaging it, but once its packaged in a exe file it throws an error here

The ./license file was created this way :

```js
var licensedata = {license:licen.license, lastpayment:data.lastpayment, macAddress:getmac.default()};

var stringtoencrypt = JSON.stringify(licensedata);
var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(stringtoencrypt, 'f8LNLIHdb9CT4KYTBF6Az9sNR2r1bMlUjqgCia0teIrg0lZ4iZ7sUSBt7cJqmYE3GrHe082eD9ajIry2');
var cptext = ciphertext.toString();

var fp = "./license";
var encdata = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(cptext));
fs.writeFileSync(fp, encdata);
```

Comment: content of ./license : U2FsdGVkX1/MB4WXQpdQ3Sju4jmoBHq9w2WsWvxPvkqH0CzeG9UknkxeZJErFxNPvt9lpXyZIGhV+Gw6lhWf99wpEa2mzr7YrGGl5Nxb6aMqVVlhe+BHrLaEixkSwHGmWb2lKrmzfkm8IiQOaq7SSnPguowuTKXn+qQKsP/fpZEXWppfo8DTGvmRaALd+4OR

Comment: The decryption itself works. Seems more like an file I/O problem to me.